# Configuring axis2.xml for clustering WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

When configuring clustering on WSO2EI, you have to edit the axis2.xml for each profile (ESB, Broker, BPMN, and Analytics).

Should the port be different for each profile in the following snippet?

```
<members>
    <member>
        <hostName>xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2</hostName>
        <port>4100</port>
    </member>
</members>
```

Assuming that all profiles will run on the same node.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is "yes" in order to avoid confusion in cluster management.
However, clustering in WSO2SP have better mechanism of utilizing the same cluster management (also worth to mention that the nature of the products is different)